# How do I set up Amazon S3 & Cloudfront to make mp4 files pubicly available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to host a video on S3 and make it publicly available through Cloudfront. I have set up my bucket in S3 and created a distribution in Cloudfront following all the guidance that I can find online, but have not been able to make it work for some reason.

This particular video is for an auto webinar in the Everwebinar application.

I am also planning to host videos for a course that I am preparing in the same way, although I would probably require better security for that.

I am a course creator, not a web developer and would really appreciate some help for what I would have thought was a very simple task that I have spent days trying to sort this out

I have tried everything that I can find online and it seems that recent changes to S3 have made some of the past advice inapplicable.

Comment: Couple of quick questions: Is your bucket private or public? does s3 bucket have bucket policy to allow cloudfront oai to access bucket? what is the error you are receiving when you are trying to access cloudfront link

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. one of the options that I have tried that setting the policy to give access to Cloudfront that I obtained from Cloudfront but that didn't work

Comment: When I try to access the vidie I get the following message: 
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>P8TPAD4QAEK1BQ1M</RequestId>
<HostId>lZSbOO9UIKp31PfAmShQ7yDD4Csobo7PPdwDaf2ImqKeOu0EpSQNbJAOoRcErBCtA2YWvoW4nPw=</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/ have you tried this? also in your cloudfront and s3 bucket settings make sure to set default root object which is usually `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks. I am not setting up a website so index.html is not appropriate - I am simply trying to give access to an mp4 file. it is set up as a REST AAPI>

Unfortunatley that reference did not seem to help, though, not being a programmer, I might have missed something.

Comment: Are there current detailed step-by-step instructions on how to do this, something that I would've expected to be pretty basic?

Comment: I think that I have sorted it out. After reducing the length of the file names for my bucket and my video, I started again and it seems to work.

thansk again for those who have tried to help me with this.

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Since you resolved the issue, please consider to post an (own) answer (adding relevant info/links/[edit]ing your OP), this might help future users and earn you rep.;)